# Need sumproduct excel formula with dynamic field

Tags: excel, dynamic

[image]

Requirement :
->green color cell need sumproduct of cells where 90% found in 1st Column with its activity wtg.
->pink color cell need sumproduct of cells where 95% found in 2nd Column with its activity wtg.
->blue cell need sumproduct of cells where 100% found in 3rd Column with its activity wtg.

Just an extract pasted here, need a dynamic formula to use it in a large data table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `SUMIF()` or `SUMIFS()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT()` like below formula then drag across as you need.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$3:$A$7)*(B3:B7=B1))
```

You can also use `SUMIFS()` like

```
=SUMIFS($A$3:$A$7,B3:B7,B1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sumifs function did not clicked me :).

Comment: It depends on excel version. `SUMPRODUCT()` should work. If it works then please accept the answer. Tick mark the answer.